# How to financially quantify optimal number of items in a release?

Tags: release-management, pricing, devops

In Don Reinertsen's book - [Principles of Product Development Flow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935401009) - the tradeoff between release size (number of stories) and release cost (regression test cost and release cost) is described like this:

[image: Product Development Flow - Optimal Batch Size]

In Ken Rubin's book - [Essential Scrum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008NAKA5O) - he talks about the benefits of smaller release sizes - being:

- Reduced cycle time
- Reduced flow variability
- Accelerate feedback
- Lower risk of failure
- Reduced overhead
- Increased motivation and urgency
- Reduced cost and schedule growth

He also uses the following way of describing this tradeoff:

[image]

They both talk about this in terms of a [U-curve optimisation problem](http://www.innolution.com/resources/glossary/u-curve-optimization). The challenge is how to quantify this.

My question is: **How to financially quantify optimal number of items in a release?**

Comment: Make some measurements, and see. It will strongly depend on who your customers are

Comment: Cool - what do I measure?

Comment: How much your customers are willing to pay for different sizes of update ( ~ light blue line ), how much dev time is used making sure everything still works as you add more features to a release ( ~ red line )

Comment: The reason you get the light blue line from pricing upgrades is a combination of "sell upgrade every T time for $X gets X/T income rate, vs 2T for $1.2X because that is all they are willing to pay for" and "money now is worth more than future money"

Comment: "only 15 percent of product developers know the cost of delay associated with their projects." This is a quote from the book. Are you saying he never elaborates on this?

Comment: Not from what I can see. How do you quantify the cost of delay?

Comment: Can cost of delay be seen as the same as opportunity cost ? What the team would be saving in man-hours, time and/or risk taking by not having the features they need in that time ? Some dimensions can be measured (man-hours saved), but others not (risk taking by not having some feature).

Comment: By the way, I don't like this kind of approach on software development. I'm still waiting to see a place where measuring software development productivity by any concrete value has increased quality or productivity. I strongly recommend reading the following 2 Joel Spolky's posts: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/09.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/HighNotes.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above has the form of

```
cost = n*BS + m/BS
```

with

- `n` = holding cost factor,
- `m` = transaction cost factor and
- `BS`= batch size.

You have to find the zero crossing of the first derivative for the minimum. The first derivative for the above is

```
n - m/(BS^2)
```

When setting that to zero you find

```
min cost = sqrt(m/n)
```

Now you can just set a fence around this to have an area instead of a single point.